# jQuery syntax for line break and input insertion

Tags: jquery

I want to place a text input with a `<br />` before it. This two alternatives seem to work equally, but which should be the syntactically correct one, if any?

Option 1:

```
let txt1 = $('<input/>').attr({
  type: 'text',
  class: 'texto'
}).appendTo('body').before('<br/>');
```

Option 2:

```
let txt1 = $('<br/><input/>').attr({
  type: 'text',
  class: 'texto'
}).appendTo('body');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, both are *syntactically* valid, since they both work. However, notice there's a subtle difference.

Using:

```
let txt1 = $('<br/><input/>').attr({
  type: 'text',
  class: 'texto'
}).appendTo('body');
```

Will cause **both** the `<br />` and the `<input />` elements to have a `class` attribute of `texto` and a `value` attribute of `text`. This of course is invalid syntax, since the `br` element cannot have a `type` attribute.

Therefore it is much better to use option 1:

```
let txt1 = $('<input/>').attr({
  type: 'text',
  class: 'texto'
}).appendTo('body').before('<br/>');
```

Since the `attr()` function is only executed on the `<input />` element, and not the `<br />`.

Comment: Ok, I supposed it, but till now wasn't sure. Thanks!